# QueryException Could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel v7
Php v7.4

could not find driver (SQL: insert into ...

Миграции проходят успешно
Но при заносе значений из формы в бд, вылазит такая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в рабочем окружении. Убедитесь, что все необходимые расширения для работы с БД установлены, убедитесь что для cli команд и запросов с вебсервера используется один и тот же бинарик.

В консоли

> php -v

и phpinfo() вывод в браузер (тут же можно и посмотреть какие расширения подключены)

P.S вот ссылка, которая может быть полезной https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/could-not-find-driver-error-in-laravel-55